# Cómo mantener el estado seleccionado de un Spinner con SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, spinner, sharedpreferences, position

he intentado mantener el estado de un **Spinner** luego de ser seleccionado y almacenado con **SharedPreferences** pero no lo he logrado, lo primero que creo es un botón para ir de la clase MainActivity a la clase SharedSpiner, una vez allí almaceno el valor seleccionado del spinner, y lo que busco es mantener el valor de ese spinner cuando vuelva a entrar a la clase SharedSpinner, tengo entendido que debo tener en cuenta la posición del spinner, a que creen que se debe?

Comparto el código del **MainActivity**

```
package alam.develop.spinnershared;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static alam.develop.spinnershared.SharedSpinner.index;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override



    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.idconfiguracion:
                SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
                String Cargaspinner = sharpref.getString("Dato", String.valueOf(index));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cargando el valor: " +Cargaspinner,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(this,SharedSpinner.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Tambien el codigo de la clase **SharedSpinner**

```
package alam.develop.spinnershared;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SharedSpinner extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public String CapturaSpinner;
    static public int index;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_spinner);

        Spinner spSpinner = findViewById(R.id.idspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Lista, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CapturaSpinner = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                index = position;
                System.out.println("Indice:"+index);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.idvolver:
            guardarPreference(this,1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El valor capturado es: " +CapturaSpinner,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
}

public void guardarPreference(Context context, int index) {
    SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();
    editor.putInt("Dato", index);
    System.out.println("Indice:"+index);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();

}
```

}

y por ultimo los recursos del archivo **XML**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">SpinnerShared</string>
    <string-array name= "Lista">
        <item></item>
        <item>23</item>
        <item>34</item>
        <item>45</item>
        <item>56</item>
        <item>67</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Adjunto las siguiente secuencia de imágenes donde resalto que el valor seleccionado no vuelve a cargar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es correcto lo que realizas, guardas el indice del elemento dentro del `Spinner`, pero el valor lo estas guardando como entero y lo estas obteniendo como String lo cual no es correcto, por cierto , no necesitas usar `commit()`, con `apply()` es suficiente:

```
public void guardarPreference(Context context, int index) {
    SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();
    editor.putInt("Dato", index);
    System.out.println("Indice:"+index);
    editor.apply();
    //editor.commit();    
}
```

Si guardas como entero el valor, obtenlo de esta forma en tu Activity `SharedSpinner`, puedes definir el 0 como valor default.

Te recomiendo guardar la posición en el Spinner cuando lo seleccionas ( dentro de `onItemSelected()`).

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_spinner);

        Spinner spSpinner = findViewById(R.id.idspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Lista, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Obtiene indice guardado en preferencias.
        SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        index = sharpref.getInt("Dato", 0);
        //Mueve a esa posición el Spinner
        spSpinner.setSelection(index);          


        spSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CapturaSpinner = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                index = position;
                System.out.println("Indice:"+index); 

                //Guarda indice de elemento seleccionado.
                guardarPreference(getApplicationContext(), position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Jorgesys, confirmo que funciono, Saludos!!

Comment: Excelente , recuerda marcar la pregunta que ayude a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [tour], un saludo!!!. @IngeArk

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo es que no tenes una lectura en la clase sharedSpinner. Vos haces lo siguiente (corregime si estoy equivocado, ya que no estoy reproduciendo el codigo, sino que lo  estoy leyendo).

- Haces una lectura del SharedReference en el botón del MainActivity.
- Cuando Seleccionas el Spinner grabas en el SharedReference.

El problema es que la clase SharedSpinner nunca recibe el valor que leiste en el MainActivity. Aqui tenes dos posibilidades, le pasas el valor por putextra al intent o haces la lectura que haces en el mainActivity apenas levanta la SharedSpinner.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.
Manteneme al tanto.

Comment: El valor de SharedReference puede ser leído en cualquier Activity de la misma aplicación, no es necesario enviarlo en el Intent.

Comment: Es correcto @ptorresi, en el Botón del MainActivity lo que intento darle la referencia al spinner de cual es el valor que debe cargar empleando el parámetro index, y por otra parte el botón volver de la clase SharedSpinner almacena el indice de la posición correctamente, pero no logro implementar esa lectura que comentas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo esta correcto, solo falta el setSelection del spinner en la activity SharedSpinner. Aunque tienes que obtener el Shared Preferences para obtener el valor que ya guardaste. Agrégalo despues del spSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

```
    SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
    int num = sharpref.getInt("Dato", index);

    spSpinner.setSelection(num);
```